# nloptr optimization stops before maxeval steps even when {x,f}tol_{rel,abs} are all set to 0

Tags: c++, r, optimization, nlopt

I am looking at the example given in [the manual of nloptr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf).

I replaced the last part of the code by

```
local_opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_MMA",
                    "xtol_rel" = 0.0,
                    "ftol_rel" = 0.0,
                    "ftol_abs" = 0.0,
                    "xtol_abs" = 0.0)
opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG",
              "xtol_rel" = 0.0,
              "ftol_rel" = 0.0,
              "ftol_abs" = 0.0,
              "xtol_abs" = 0.0,
              "maxeval" = 100000,
              "local_opts" = local_opts )
res <- nloptr( x0=x0,
               eval_f=eval_f,
               lb=lb,
               ub=ub,
               eval_g_ineq=eval_g_ineq,
               eval_g_eq=eval_g_eq,
               opts=opts)
print( res )
```

That is, I changed xtol/ftol rel/abs to all be 0, for both the main solver and the local solver.Note both of them use gradient based algorithm.  I also increased the max number of steps from 1k to 100k.

However the solver terminates much earlier, at 3k steps.

> Call: nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = eval_f, lb = lb, ub = ub, eval_g_ineq =
>   eval_g_ineq, 
>       eval_g_eq = eval_g_eq, opts = opts)
>
> Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.2
>
> NLopt solver status: 3 ( NLOPT_FTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped
>   because ftol_rel or  ftol_abs (above) was reached. )
>
> Number of Iterations....: 3132  Termination conditions:  xtol_rel:
>   0 ftol_rel: 0 ftol_abs: 0 xtol_abs: 0 maxeval: 1e+05  Number of
>   inequality constraints:  1  Number of equality constraints:    1 
>   Optimal value of objective function:  17.0140172891563  Optimal value
>   of controls: 1 4.743 3.82115 1.379408

Looking at the [c++ implementation of nlopt](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/blob/master/util/stop.c#L32), it seems that this should not happen. The termination conditions given by the various tolerance levels are in terms of strict inequality. So am I missing something about the meaning of the solver status "NLOPT_FTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because ftol_rel or ftol_abs (above) was reached." ?

Thanks!
  John

Comment: If you execute: `nloptr.print.options()` you can read that 'xtol_rel' must be greater than 0. However, I am not sure that the example code in the manual is correct either because when I execute that code I get a warning message: ``No termination criterium specified, using default (relative x-tolerance = 1e-04)`, despite the fact that xtol_rel was (attempted) to be set at a lower value. So what problem is really bothering you? The program does need to have a stopping criterion.

Comment: @42: Thank you for quick response. I would simply like the stopping criterion to be based on maxeval steps. The problem is that using gradient based local solver I am getting inferior objective than with derivative free solvers, but the latter comes with its own problem (machine precision reached etc). So I have also tried very small xtol_rel etc and early stopping does go away. I guess for my own more complicated problem, early stopping occurs because I got stuck in a local minimum. Could you point me to the R implementation where the xtol_rel etc get reset to a default value greater than 0?

Comment: I just ran the first example I came to in the reference you cited. The "res" print output included the solver status "NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached." (And that was the same code that warned about no "terminiation criterium").

Comment: I also had the problem that nloptr stopped iterating too early stating NLopt solver status: 3. Now I found a solution: use "algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_SBPLX"

Comment: Any solution to this problem yet? I also have this same scenario where rather than stopping on the criteria given, the optimization is stopping on NLOPT_FTOL_REACHED